# iMacros blocks on redirections

Tags: imacros, redirect

I'm making automated scripts using iMacros. At a certain point in my procedure, a webpage is called and it redirects immediately to a payment provider where I should continue my tests. At the arrival at the payment page (after being redirected), the script times out. However, when I run the same rules directly from the payment page, it works correctly.

I don't see what could influence the script, other then the redirection.

Procedure:

1. Access to form
2. Fill in form
3. Confirm basket
4. Click to go to payment provider
5. Loading redirection page, building payment provider data to send along
6. Redirection to payment provider
7. Click on credit card to continue payment. TAG command doesn't find the credit card image, but when I run a different script with the same command, but from this page as start point, it works.

Any suggestions how I can get iMacros to handle re directions?

Comment: could you please provide all the debug info, and post the macro too

Comment: Please provide your code, so we can see what is not working :)